# Powershell Google GeoLocation script

Tags: google-maps, powershell, google-maps-api-3, powershell-4.0

```
Api key here

function Get-ComputerGeoLocation ()
{

echo debug 1
# Windows Location API
$mylocation = new-object –ComObject LocationDisp.LatLongReportFactory

# Get Status 
$mylocationstatus = $mylocation.status
If ($mylocationstatus -eq "4")
{
    # Windows Location Status returns 4, so we're "Running"
    echo debug 2
    # Get Latitude and Longitude from LatlongReport property
    $latitude = $mylocation.LatLongReport.Latitude 
    $longitude = $mylocation.LatLongReport.Longitude

    if ($latitude -ne $null -or $longitude -ne $Null)
    {
        echo debug 3
        # Retrieve Geolocation from Google Geocoding API
        $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
        Write-host "Retrieving geolocation for" $($latitude) $($longitude)
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=$latitude,$longitude'&'amp;sensor=true"
        $locationinfo = $webClient.DownloadString($url) 
        echo debug 4
        [xml][/xml]$doc = $locationinfo
        # Verify the response
        if ($doc.GeocodeResponse.status -eq "OK")
        {
            $street_address = $doc.GeocodeResponse.result | Select-Object -Property formatted_address, Type | Where-Object -Property Type -eq "street_address" 
            $geoobject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $geoobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Address -Value $street_address.formatted_address
            $geoobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name latitude -Value $mylocation.LatLongReport.Latitude
            $geoobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name longitude -Value $mylocation.LatLongReport.longitude
            $geoobject | format-list
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Warning "Request failed, unable to retrieve Geo locatiion information from Geocoding API"  
        }
    }
    Else
        {
            write-warning "Latitude or Longitude data missing"
        }
    }

Else
{
    switch($mylocationstatus)
    {
    # All possible status property values as defined here: 
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317716(v=vs.85).aspx
    0 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Report not supported"} 
    1 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Error"}
    2 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Access denied"} 
    3 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Initializing" } 
    4 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Running"} 
    }

    If ($mylocationstatus -eq "3")
        {
        write-host "Windows Loction platform is $mylocationstatuserr" 
        sleep 5
        Get-ComputerGeoLocation
        }
    Else
        {
        write-warning "Windows Loction platform: Status:$mylocationstatuserr"
        }
}
} # end function
Get-ComputerGeoLocation
```

So I am typing in the terminal "get-computergeolocation"

The error is:

```
At C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\files\powershell\computerLocation.ps1:72 char:77
+ ... write-warning "Windows Loction platform: Status:$mylocationstatuserr"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\files\powershell\computerLocation.ps1:4 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I am not sure, it is giving back a syntax error, but I don't think it is a syntax error.
I sifted through the code to see if there was a syntax error and came up with nothing, at least with what the terminal was spitting out.

The code should find my latitude and longitude and give me an address (end result). This is going to be tied together in another program that determines the users home address based on IP.

====================================
**UPDATED**
I updated the script. I took out everything that wasn't important to keep it super simple to try to narrow down the error.

```
function Get-123(){
    $env:GoogleGeoloc_API_Key = "key"
    echo debug 1
    # Windows Location API
    $mylocation = new-object –ComObject LocationDisp.LatLongReportFactory

    # Get Status 
    $mylocationstatus = $mylocation.status
    If ($mylocationstatus -eq "4"){
        # Windows Location Status returns 4, so we're 
        echo debug 2
        # Get Latitude and Longitude from LatlongReport property
        $latitude = $mylocation.LatLongReport.Latitude 
        $longitude = $mylocation.LatLongReport.Longitude

        if ($latitude -ne $null -or $longitude -ne $Null){
            echo debug 3
            # Retrieve Geolocation from Google Geocoding API
            $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
            Write-host "Retrieving geolocation for" $($latitude) $($longitude)
            #$u = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=$latitude,$longitude"
            #$r = '&'
            #$l = "amp;sensor=true"
            $url = “https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=$latitude,$longitude&sensor=true”
            $locationinfo = $webClient.DownloadString($url) 
            echo debug 4
            [xml]$doc = $locationinfo
            # Verify the response
            if ($doc.GeocodeResponse.status -eq "OK"){
                $street_address = $doc.GeocodeResponse.result | Select-Object -Property formatted_address, Type | Where-Object {$_.Property -eq "street_address"}
                $geoobject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $geoobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Address -Value $street_address.formatted_address
                $geoobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name latitude -Value $mylocation.LatLongReport.Latitude
                $geoobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name longitude -Value $mylocation.LatLongReport.longitude
                $geoobject | format-list
            }

        }
    }

} # end function
#Get-ComputerGeoLocation
get-123
```

I Can't find this syntax error.... I am not even sure it is a syntax error....

```
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\computerLocation.ps1:36 char:148
+ ... atted_address, Type | Where-Object {$_.Property -eq "street_address"}
+                                                                        ~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\computerLocation.ps1:4 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Comment: You probably want to remove your API key.

Comment: `[xml][/xml]$doc = $locationinfo` isn't valid. Just `[xml]` I guess.

Comment: Yeah originally it was that, but powershell can't interpret & without it being in quotes by itself for some reason.

Comment: PowerShell can perfectly interpret a string with an ampersand (`&`) in it, if you run the code without the single quotes `'` in the `$url` variable do you get the same error?

Comment: `The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler removing the [xml] portion didn't fix any error, but it might have prevented a future error.

Comment: no update on this thing?

Comment: went through and changed all of them... Nothing worked. I'm confused at this point.